# Worklight - jQuery mobile onclick() not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing an application using *Worklight Studio 6.1*
My problem is when I click the button in the html page, it does nothing.

The following is my Code:

SelectPosition.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Select Position</title>
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <link href="../jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/controllers/SelectPositionController.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="#" data-role="button" id="confirmBtn" onclick="confirmClick()">Confirm</a>

</body>
</html>
```

SelectPositionController.js

```
function confirmClick() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
}
```

Thank you for all suggestion and solutions.

Ps. My html file is located in *"apps/Insurance/common/views/SelectPosition.html"* 
and my js file is located in *"apps/Insurance/common/js/controllers/SelectPositionController.js"*

**[EDIT]**

I merge all my .html files into main.html file and everything is OK. Thank you for all solutions ;)

Comment: Preview the app in Chrome, open the chrome dev tools and click the button - what do you see in the console?

Comment: Also mention if you have Navigated from index.html to this views/SelectPosition.html and most importantly - HOW. You may have lost the Worklight context if you navigate w/out taking into account that worklight is a single-page application (meaning, you need to be careful when using multi-pages).

Comment: Have you also tried just writing the script in the head tags with "<script>" tags to see if it runs. That could confirm whether it's a file navigation error, or a js syntax error

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery-mobile then avoid the adding attribute in html tag
Add the click event through jquery code like

```
$('#control-id').on('click',function(){
      //Place code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/66Qbx/1/

**HTML:**

```
 <a href="#" data-role="button" id="confirmBtn">Confirm</a>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function() {
  $('#confirmBtn').on('click',function(){
       //Place code here
      alert("I am an alert box!");
    });
});
```